# Increasing the speed of a ball in a brick breaker game

Tags: unity-game-engine

just starting a tuto and I'd like to constantly increase the speed of my ball, but damn I'm so bad at maths I can't even figure how to do, here's what I do at the moment :

```
 // I'm giving the first force (random x) when you engage the ball, in the Start method
 System.Random xForce = new System.Random();
 rigidBody.AddForce(new Vector2(xForce.Next((int)-speed, (int)speed), speed);

 // Later, in the Update code, I use this
 rigidBody.AddForce(rigidBody.velocity* speedUp);
```

speed and speedUp are public variables.

What is bothering me is when I add my first force, I guess that a Vector2(speed, speed) will make a faster ball than (0, speed) right ? So I'd like a way to change the direction of my force, but with the same speed resulting for the eye of the player.

Also, when I increase my speed, I do velocity* speedUp, which means (I still guess) that a Vector2(speed, speed) will increase more than a (0, speed) right ? So I'd like to increase it in the same way no matter the direction of my ball.

I don't know if I'm being clear, I read about normalized vectors on a thread but I don't understand it that's why I'm asking your help guys, thanks in advance !

Comment: There's a couple ways you can handle adjusting your horizontal direction. I would recommend a system that checks the point the ball hits your platform at relative to the center, so that the further to the right/left side of the platform it hits then the more velocity is added to the right/left of the ball. This gives the player a way to somewhat aim and causes variance in the ball's x velocity.

Comment: Beyond that, I think you can get away with just reallocating your speed up directly on the ball's current velocity with something like `rigidBody.velocity = rigidBody.velocity * speedUp;`.

Comment: Also a possible idea for implementation would be to have the speed up occur only when it bounces (either off a surface or the player controlled platform). The reason I would recommend this is to allow a player better prediction for how fast a ball is moving at a given moment unlike a update over time which speeds up the ball mid travel between surfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after a lot of research what I needed was to cap the length of the velocity vector, I got it using the Vector2.ClampMagnitude function :

```
System.Random xForce = new System.Random();
Vector2 direction = new Vector2(xForce.Next((int)-speed, (int)speed), speed);
Vector2 cappedDirection = (Vector2.ClampMagnitude(direction, speed));
rigidBody.AddForce(cappedDirection, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

Then in my update code, it seems that I just have to use the normalized vector. From what I read a normalized version of your vector keeps the direction with a magnitude of 1 :

```
rigidBody.AddForce(rigidBody.velocity.normalized * speedUp, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

From what I tested it's working, sorry guys it seems that I wasn't clear about what I asked, I just did want the same speed no matter the direction.

Answer (score 0):

This line has unbalanced parenthesis:

```
rigidBody.AddForce(new Vector2(xForce.Next((int)-speed, (int)speed), speed);
```

Also, you probably want to use floating point numbers instead of integers.
Try this instead:

```
System.Random xForce = new System.Random();
rigidBody.AddForce(new Vector2(xForce.NextDouble()*speed,
                               xForce.NextDouble()*speed));
```

The last line looks fine though:

```
rigidBody.AddForce(rigidBody.velocity* speedUp);
```